# Use of type generics while trying to implement a List-like View class in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm looking to build an `IndexedList` that would work just like the SwiftUI `List` View but that provides a closure with `(element, index) -> RowContent` vs. the current `(element) -> RowContent`.

One thing I haven't find is how you can assign `init()` generics to the class instance when you don't know the type at the class level.

If you look at one of the `List` View init signature, you can see it uses local generics:

```
 public init<Data, RowContent>(_ data: Data, selection: Binding<Set<SelectionValue>>?, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Content == ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, HStack<RowContent>>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable
```

However `Data` being a generic type at the `init()` method level, how can you define it at the class level so you can do `self.data = data`?

Tried `Data` and `RandomAccessCollection`:

```swift
struct IndexedList<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
  let data: RandomAccessCollection // <- type issue
  let selection: Binding<Set<SelectionValue>>?
  let rowContent: (Data.Element) -> View // <- type issue
  var body: some View {
    let withIndex = self.data.enumerated().map({ $0 })
    return List(withIndex, id: \.element.id) { index, element in
      self.rowContent(index, element)
    }
  }
  public init<Data, RowContent>(_ data: Data, selection: Binding<Set<SelectionValue>>?, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element, index: number) -> RowContent) where Content == ForEach<Data, Data.Element.ID, HStack<RowContent>>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable {
    self.data = data
    self.selection = selection
    self.rowContent = rowContent
  }
}
```

But it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think below one line code that do the same is just simpler...

```
List(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { i, item in
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your requirements to the type, and you won't need to bother with constraining the initializer.

```swift
struct IndexedList<
  Data: RandomAccessCollection,
  SelectionValue: Hashable,
  HStackContent: View
>: View
where Data.Element: Hashable & Identifiable {
  typealias Selection = Binding< Set<SelectionValue> >?
  typealias RowContent =
    (EnumeratedSequence<[Data.Element]>.Element)
    -> ForEach< Data, Data.Element.ID, HStack<HStackContent> >

  let data: Data
  let selection: Selection
  let rowContent: RowContent

  var body: some View {
    List(
      Array( data.enumerated() ),
      id: \.element,
      rowContent: rowContent
    )
  }

  public init(
    _ data: Data,
    selection: Selection,
    @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping RowContent
  )  {
    self.data = data
    self.selection = selection
    self.rowContent = rowContent
  }
}
```